# How to get rid of microseconds in MariaDB?

Tags: datetime, mariadb

In MySQL this query returns something like `2016-06-13 08:03:54` ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53da3/1)):

```
SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(d, 0), NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) FROM test
```

In MariaDB it returns a microseconds part: `2016-06-13 08:03:54.000000`.

This confuses our application. How can I turn it off (not only in this query, but system-wide)?

Comment: Are you using MariaDB Connector/J?. See [`useFractionalSeconds`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/date_format/) and [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/microseconds-in-mariadb/):

```
SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(d, 0), NOW()) FROM test
```

Comment: This would mean I have to change a lot of queries, that's why I wrote "not only in this query, but system-wide".

Comment: @AndreKR since you use `- INTERVAL` I am not sure if even `DATE_FORMAT` will help you. I guess you already read about [microseconds in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/microseconds-in-mariadb/)?